# Flipping a Number Using PHP

Tags: php

Hi I have a number in php, and I need to flip it (eg. "1112"-->"2111"). How can this be performed?
Should I use an array, or is there a special function?

Comment: strrev if you consider your number a string.

Answer (score 3):

You use the following [strrev](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) function in PHP.

```
$reverse = strrev("1112")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using JAVASCRIPT**

```
function strrev(str) 
 {  
  return str.split("").reverse().join(""); 
}  

alert(strrev("1112"));
```

**Using PHP**

```
echo strrev("1112");
```

Comment: In JavaScript, yes, that would work, but this isn't a JavaScript question.

Comment: Originally, this was tagged as javascript, which is why this answer is javascript.